# Looking for help designing a While loop in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

Im designing an RPG for a class project, working on a gimmicky idea of an item that can be configured to give certain bonuses to existing classes.

But for some reason getting the `While` loop to loop properly and not repeat the `print("invalid choice")` for eons AND getting the function itself to work, are beyond me.

*Any help is appreciated!!*

```
#PowerTreadFunction
def askPowerTread():
    choice = none
    while choice not in ['A','B','C']:
        print("Invalid choice.")
    choice = input("""Your Power Treads offer the following configurations which each                give distinct bonuses, choose now:\n    
 a) DAMAGE\nb) DEFENSE\nc) ARMOR CLASS\n""")


    if choice == 'A':
        printSlow("Configuring Power Treads for Damage, you now recieve a +5 damage bonus")
        player[DAM] += 5

    elif choice == 'B':
         printSlow("Configuring Power Treads for Defense, you now recieve a +5 defense bonus")
         player[DEF] +=5

    elif choice == 'C':
         printSlow("Configuring Power Treads for Armor Class, you now recieve a +5 armor class bonus")
         player[AC] +=5
```

Comment: I don't know python, but you have too many " at the line 'choice = input', btw DOTA

Comment: nope, `"""` are valid string delimiters in python.

Comment: sorry then, can we see the whole 'asPowerTread()' ? currently it looks like a part only

Comment: i used the """ because i wanted to format the choice nicely, i pasted the function in its entirety, if its missing something thats my own novice error ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#PowerTreadFunction
def askPowerTread():
    choice = none
    while choice not in ['A','B','C']:
        print("Invalid choice.")
    choice = input("""Your Power Treads offer the following configurations which each                give distinct bonuses, choose now:\n    
 a) DAMAGE\nb) DEFENSE\nc) ARMOR CLASS\n""")
```

You assign choice to `none` (I think you meant `None`) and then enter the loop without changing it.

`choice = input(...)` is outside the while loop so it will never execute. Try:

```
def askPowerTread():
        while True:
            choice = input(...)
            if choice in [...]:
                break
            else:
                print('{choice} is an invalid choice'.format(choice=choice))
```

To demonstrate the difference between `none` and `None`:

```
>>> type(none)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    type(none)
NameError: name 'none' is not defined
>>> type(None)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>>
```

Comment: so none is different than None? ffffffff

Comment: Yes, Python is case sensitive. `none` would be the name of a variable while `None` is the keyword.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is the indentation:

```
def askPowerTread():
    choice = None
    while choice not in ['A','B','C']:
        print("Invalid choice.")
    choice = input(...)
```

here you're looping over the print statement, but not asking for a new choice to be made, which is outof the while block.

```
def askPowerTread():
    choice = None
    while choice not in ['A','B','C']:
        print("Invalid choice.")
        choice = input(...)
```

should solve your problem. Once that's solved, the code you've pasted looks fine to me.

edit: @IanAuld, You're right, to solve this:

```
PROMPT="""\
 Your Power Treads offer the following configurations which each
 give distinct bonuses, choose now:
  a) DAMAGE
  b) DEFENSE
  c) ARMOR CLASS
```

"""

```
def askPowerTread():
    choice = input(PROMPT)
    while choice not in ['A','B','C']:
        print("Invalid choice.")
        choice = input(PROMPT)
```

Comment: This will always give the user a message of 'Invalid Choice' even before they make a selection. Which is probably not desired behavior.

Comment: so indents are all inline, and ive got the error :NameError: global name 'none' is not defined. I've gotten this error before, im attempting to require an answer, either A B or C, and once that answer is chosen, break the loop and move on with all of our lives

Comment: none takes an uppercase `n`: `None`. See my edit for a better version

Comment: gahhhhh ive been beating myself up over a missed capital letter for like 45 minutes